# Getting TimeSeet time period in Project Online using JavaScript JSOM

Tags: sharepoint-addin, project-server, project-online

I'm creating a new TimeSheet app for Project Online, I have followed this article to recuperate the current user assignments projects [Walkthrough: Create a SharePoint-hosted Project Server add-in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj873844.aspx#pj15_StatusingApp_Example).

But what i need now is to get the TimeSheet time Period for the same projects using JavaScript. There is anyone who know how I can do that.